Hash function for binary data
Is this implementation of hashing function for binary data ok? It is meant to be used by concrete objects satisfying  Hash requirements, i.e. to be called from within Hash::operator.
size_t hash_binary_buffer(const void* data, size_t count) {
    std::string_view sv{(const char*)data, count};
    return std::hash<std::string_view>(sv);
}

One way to use this function would be to memcpy binary values comprising the state of the object into binary array and then pass that array to the above function.
P.S. I would like to use the above function when implementing hasher objects for arbitrary key types for unordered map/set containers.
P.S.S. Looking at various specializations of standard supplied hashers, there is no obvious way how use the following struct (or something of that nature) as  container key:
struct Record {
    uint8_t type;
    uint64_t offset;
    uint8_t header_type;
    uint32_t header_size;
};

So I came up with following implementation for the hasher type (showing only relevant parts):
size_t Hasher::operator(const Record& r) const {
    char data[2*sizeof(uint8_t) + sizeof(uint64_t) + sizeof(uint32_t)];
    char* dst = data;

    memcpy(dst, &r.type, sizeof(r.type));
    dst += sizeof(r.type);

    memcpy(dst, &r.offset, sizeof(r.offset));
    dst += sizeof(r.offset);

    memcpy(dst, &r.header_type, sizeof(r.header_type));
    dst += sizeof(r.header_type);

    memcpy(dst, &r.header_size, sizeof(r.header_size));
    dst += sizeof(r.header_size);

    return hash_binary_buffer(data, sizeof(data));
}

When dealing with packed POD types, then object's address can be passed directly to hasher without the need to copy every field separately.
P.S.S.S. Since the original question is of yes/no type, maybe it would be better to ask how to use arbitrary types as key for unordered map/set containers? I am aware that there is Boost.ContainerHash, but I can rely on standard C++ facilities only.

Depends on what "ok" means. I would say if it works in your application and does what you expect then it is "ok".

Looks ok. And you don't need memcpy, you can pass a pointer to your object directly to this.

uh, oh. regarding to your intended use: language lawyers will tell this to you in standardeese, but you should only copy the bits that are actually used by the object, otherwise the rest (garbage) will mess up your hash.

also, hashing things like pointers could be ok or could be horribly wrong depending on the meaning of those pointers and what you'll use the hash value for.

why make a detour via void* when anyhow you want a char* ?

void* is to stress the fact, that we are dealing with binary (i.e. non-textual) data.

@pic11 That’s not what void* means or communicates. In fact, char* is the correct type to communicate binary data (nowadays you could also use byte_t*).

A hash function require that for a given input, the same result is always given (within a given context). Typically, this means that if two objects x and y compare equal, their hash should also compare equal. However, you can have objects that compare equal but whose representations are not identical. For example two identical vectors will each be represented by different internal pointer values. Using the proposed hash function, their hash would very likely not compare equal because their memory representation is different.

It depends on when you want hashes to be equal.  Is const void* data pointing to a std::string?  If so, should equal strings produce equal hashes?  Your solution would fail at that.

just to summarize the disucssion on now deleted answer: The actual question is "Is this a good hash for arbitrary types?" and I'd suggest to change the title, because whether hash_binary_buffer is ok to hash binary data isnt the crucial part of the quesiton.

fwiw, you dont need to keep "P.S" in the question. It is not necessary that one can trace the history directly in the quesiton, the history can be viewed here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78347781/revisions. Often it is easier to read if you only keep the current state

Hashing your Record as a flat array of bytes is going to be slow, due to the intermediate transformation that's needed. Instead, hash each field of the record using std::hash then combine them with something like boost::hash_combine:
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_set>

// Borrowed from Boost.ContainerHash
// https://github.com/boostorg/container_hash/blob/ee5285bfa64843a11e29700298c83a37e3132fcd/include/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp#L471
template <typename T>
void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v) {
    static constexpr auto digits = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::digits;
    static_assert(digits == 64 || digits == 32);
    
    if constexpr (digits == 64) {
        // https://github.com/boostorg/container_hash/blob/ee5285bfa64843a11e29700298c83a37e3132fcd/include/boost/container_hash/detail/hash_mix.hpp#L67
        std::size_t x = seed + 0x9e3779b9 + std::hash<T>()(v);
        const std::size_t m = 0xe9846af9b1a615d;
        x ^= x >> 32;
        x *= m;
        x ^= x >> 32;
        x *= m;
        x ^= x >> 28;
        seed = x;
    }
    else { // 32-bits
        // https://github.com/boostorg/container_hash/blob/ee5285bfa64843a11e29700298c83a37e3132fcd/include/boost/container_hash/detail/hash_mix.hpp#L88
        std::size_t x = seed + 0x9e3779b9 + std::hash<T>()(v);
        const std::size_t m1 = 0x21f0aaad;
        const std::size_t m2 = 0x735a2d97;
        x ^= x >> 16;
        x *= m1;
        x ^= x >> 15;
        x *= m2;
        x ^= x >> 15;
        seed = x;
    }
}

struct Record {
    uint8_t type;
    uint64_t offset;
    uint8_t header_type;
    uint32_t header_size;

    friend bool operator==(const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) {
        return std::tie(lhs.type, lhs.offset, lhs.header_type, lhs.header_size) ==
               std::tie(rhs.type, rhs.offset, rhs.header_type, rhs.header_size);
    }
};

namespace std
{
template <>
struct hash<Record>
{
    size_t operator()(Record r) const noexcept {
        size_t seed = 0;
        hash_combine(seed, hash<uint8_t> {}(r.type));
        hash_combine(seed, hash<uint64_t>{}(r.offset));
        hash_combine(seed, hash<uint8_t> {}(r.header_type));
        hash_combine(seed, hash<uint32_t>{}(r.header_size));
        return seed;
    }
};
} // namespace std

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<Record> records;
    records.insert(Record{1, 2, 3, 4});
    return 0;
}

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/51bEEzeqr
You sometimes see hashes being combined directly with only a bitwise XOR operation, but that requires that those hashes be randomly distributed. std::hash for integer types are the identify function in some implementations, so they won't be randomly distributed.
